General Girsanov Theorem
Proposition 1.16 of Lawler's $\textit{Conformally Invariant Processes in the Plane}$ states, in a slightly simpler form, if
$Z_t = \int\limits_{0}^{t}H_sdB_s$,
where $H_s$ is a continuous local martingale with respect to a probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbf{P})$,
$M_t=\exp({Z_t-\langle Z \rangle}_t/2)$
is the corresponding exponential martingale (i.e. $dM_t=M_tdZ_t$), and $\mathbf{Q}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_t)$ whose Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to $\mathbf{P}$ is $M_t$, then
$X_t=Z_t - \int\limits_{0}^{t}M_r^{-1}d\langle Z \rangle_r$
is a $\mathbf{Q}$-martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$.
My understanding, based on Lawler's previous sections, is that we need to show that the $dt$ term vanishes in $d(X_tM_t)$, but writing out the algebra, I get
$d(X_tM_t) = X_tdM_t + M_tdX_t + d\langle X, M \rangle_t = X_tM_tdZ_t + M_tdZ_t - d\langle Z \rangle_t + M_td\langle Z \rangle_t$,
and the $dt$ terms don't cancel.

That should be $X_t=Z_t-\langle Z\rangle_t$.

Okay. I figured @JohnDawkins, but I don’t like to assume an author is incorrect, so I wanted to make sure here.
